# Why can't inverseList function be implemented？

Tags: c, reverse, singly-linked-list, function-definition

The linked list realizes reversal through the stack, but does not jump when it runs to inverseList. Why can't inverseList function be implemented？

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

typedef struct lnode{
    int data;
    struct lnode *next;
}lnode,*Linklist;

Linklist createList(int n){
    Linklist L,p,q;
    int i;
    L = (lnode*)malloc(sizeof(lnode));
    if(!L){
        return 0;
    }
    L->next = NULL;
    q = L;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        p = (lnode*) malloc(sizeof(lnode));
        printf("enter：\n");
        scanf("%d",&p->data);
        p->next = NULL;
        q->next = p;
        q = p;
    }
    return L;
}

Linklist inverseList(Linklist h){
    Linklist res;
    int arr[10];
    int i=0;
    while(h->next != NULL){
        arr[i] = h->data;
        i++;
        h = h->next;
    }

    if(-1 == i){
        res->data = arr[i];
        i--;
        res = res->next;
    }
    return res;
}

void printList(Linklist h){
    Linklist p = h->next;
    while(p!=NULL){
        printf("%d ",p->data);
        p = p->next;
    }
}

int main(){
    Linklist pHead = NULL;
    int n;

    printf("enter the number of value:\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    pHead = createList(n);
    printf("value in the list：\n");
    printList(pHead);
    printf("\n----------\n");
    inverseList(pHead);
    printList(pHead);
    return 0;
}
```

The linked list realizes reversal through the stack, but does not jump when it runs to inverseList. Why can't inverseList function be implemented？

Comment: Your function inverseList just does not make sense as the function createList that creates a dummy node.

Comment: The implementation of `inverseList()` has *undefined behavior* and it's return value is not even used by the caller.

Comment: OT: Please separate list and node creation from input and output. That will make the code cleaner, and easier to read, understand and maintain. And also easier to test and debug. I also recommend you really separate the list from the nodes. So you have one structure for the list, with a `head` and a `tail` (to make tail-insertions easier); And one separate structure for the nodes.

Comment: `#include <cstdio>` ? Did I miss another memo on a new C standard library header set? Last I checked that was a C++ header.

Comment: Somewhat OT: if you think you need a dummy node for your list, you're doing it wrong. It only complicates everything.

Answer (score 1):

Your list can be treated as a stack.

To create a new list which is the reverse of an existing list, then iterate over the original list and add all values to the head of the new list. The new list is now the exact reverse of the first original list.

If you should reverse the original list, then do as above, then delete all nodes from the original list, and exchange the heads of the original and new list.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are compiling your program as a C++ program. These headers

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
```

are C++ headers.

In C you need to write

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

But in any case your code is entirely wrong.

For example the function `createList` creates a dummy first node with uninitialized data member `data`. So for example it is unclear when the list is empty: whether when the pointer to the head node is equal to `NULL` or when the list has a single dummy node. And moreover the uninitialized data member next is used within the function `inverseList` in this while loop

```
while(h->next != NULL){
    arr[i] = h->data;
    //...
```

The list shall not have a dummy node.

The function `inverseList` does not make sense. For example why within the function there is created an array with a magic number of elements. Or for example when this condition in the if statement

```
if(-1 == i){
```

is satisfied. Or why within the function there is used the uninitialized pointer `res`.

```
Linklist res;
//...
res->data = arr[i];
```

If the list does not contain a dummy node (and it shall not contain it) then the function `inverseList` can look very simply. For example

```
Linklist inverseList( Linklist head )
{
    Linklist new_head = NULL;

    while ( head != NULL )
    {
        current = head;
        head = head->next;
        current->next = new_head;
        new_head = current;
    }

    return new_head;
}
```

and in main you need to write

```
pHead = inverseList(pHead);
```